# hex number case change with notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, replace, notepad

in a sentence in a file in a far off galaxy
"uint32_t per         = 0x400e10b4u;"

i want to change the case of all the hex numbers in header files using notepad++ find and replace with regex.

i can find the "400e10b4u" part of the number using the expression "(= 0x)(\w+)" in the find box, but cannot figure out how to replace the lowercase to upper case.

Notepad version 7.5.6 so im led to believe it can be done

Comment: I don't know if Notepad++ has extended features I'm not aware of, but I think this would require six different substitutions, one for each letter.

Comment: @Daniel, do you mean find and change 0x400(e)10b4u, then do the same for 0x400e(1)0b4u all the way to the end of the number

Comment: I meant find all the `a`s in hex numbers and replace them with `A`, then do the same for `b` to `B`, etc. Given that `\U` exists in Notepad++, I'd g with that instead.

Comment: @Daniel, \U\1 changes all the lower case to upper case in the notepad version i have

Comment: Yeah, that's a better option than what I was suggesting. I just didn't know that Notepad++ supported it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex: `(?<=0x)(\w+)`

Replace with: `\U$1`

\U is for UpperCase Transformation

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qr5DnM/1)

Comment: Apparently not. Have I been living under a rock? There's no such thing as lowercase or uppercase digits, my friend. If you're expecting a specific output, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50421387/edit) your question and include it there.

Comment: \u$1 in notepad not \U$1

Comment: @Matt not quite working, using Regex: (?<= 0x400)(\w+), selects 0x400(e0b4u) ok. But then Replace with: \U$1 gives the result of 0x400(E)0b4u leaving the b and the u unchanged

Comment: @joeblogs, I just downloaded Notepad++ v7.5.6 and confirmed that `\U\1` gives the expected output

Comment: @Matt cheers for taking the time, im using f....... win10 so im thinking there may be some sort of bug, but after trying numerous ways to open/close the find/replace window i can confirm that it did finally work with \U\1